# ScholarOne Manuscripts status is 'Awaiting Referee selection' for nearly 3 months

Tags: peer-review, journal-workflow

I submitted an article to a journal using ScholarOne manuscripts on 20th February. it is now nearly 3 months and it hasn't got beyond 'awaiting referee selection'. I have emailed to ask, politely, if it will be sent to reviewers and if I can help by suggesting reviewers' names. I have received no reply. 
Do people think this is normal / reasonable? 
What, if anything, should I do next?
Thanks.